# Android webview shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not called

Tags: android, webview, http-headers, android-3.0-honeycomb

In my application, shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is not called on Honeycombe 3.2 version. I have tested it on 2.2 and 4.0.1 and they all are working fine.

Is it a bug in Honeycomb? How can I work around it?

I need to send the custom header for every request in shouldOverrideUrlLoading()

```
view.loadUrl(url,headers);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is not triggered when the request is POST (maybe this is the reason).

Comment: @SYLARRR I tried both GET and POST on other version and it works.

Comment: This function is often times never called. I've found the same problem on a number of websites include www.youtube.com

I haven't dug deep enough to find out why, but basically this function is unreliable.

Comment: @Lee It is only happening in honeycomb, other versions are functioning well.

Answer (score 11):

This method will only be called when the user performs the navigation.  It won't always be called if the website redirects the user.  A common scenario for this is a website using AJAX to change the content of the page or redirect the user.

Check out the other callbacks in WebViewClient to find one that fits your needs: onLoadResource,  onPageStarted. In your case you are targetting API level 11+, so shouldInterceptRequest is also available to you.

Comment: none of these 3 methods are called but on few occasions I found from logs they actually got triggered! is this routine unreliable?